Car LED circuit
Can someone help me identify this big green and small red circular component.

This is green part, has 3 terminals attached to it. You can see 2 of them on the picture, the other one is attached to LED on the other side

This is the red component


This looks like a xenon bulb, not LED.

I guess you are right

In which case it's likely an inductor for a voltage boost converter.

Try desoldering the components for testing, then test their resistance and capacitance. You can use a Transistor Tester - Amazon - gm328a tester assembled SMT to test many simple components.

It's a ballast for an HID (high intensity discharge) headlight lamp.
The cylindrical device is a gas discharge device that's part of the ignition circuit.
The green potted device is probably the HV transformer used for ignition. There is probably another transformer used to supply the current once ignition has been achieved.
You can find a Microchip reference design for an HID ballast here.
To properly control an HID lamp from ignition to stable operation as it warms is non-trivial- so often there is a processor of some kind involved. You can see the control system compensating if you have a car with this kind of headlight.
Like CFLs, their time has pretty much come and gone, so they'll probably be a weird curiosity in another 20 years.


Is the spark gap part of normal operation? How does the voltage doubler fit in? Interesting circuit. Thanks for including it

@MicroservicesOnDDD Before the lamp ignites there is a relatively large AC voltage across the lamp. The voltage is doubled and fed to the arc gap, and thence to the transformer where it generates some tens of kV to start the lamp- and when it ignites the voltage is decreased so that the arc gap no longer arcs (and the current increases at the lower voltage)

The red component appears to be a gas discharge tube.
Like, for instance, the following P/Ns:
B88069X8910B502
2031-15T-SMLF
B88069X4880S102
Makes sense -- Xenon lights are driven by high voltage and this seems like a necessary protection circuit in case of missing/broken lamp.
I don't know about the green component, but considering it is 3 pins it may be a non-isolated step-up transformer to drive the Xenon lamp, but I am speculating.
